# Python Rounded Variable print 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the next snippet in a program:

```
#weight in kg
weight = float(input('Enter your weight: '))
#height in cm
height = float(input('Enter your height: '))

bmi_metric = weight/(height**2)/(100**2)
print("{:.2f}".format(bmi_metric))
```

The problem is when I try to round even with round() function it spits 0 in console. If I let unformatted it gives me the right number with a lot of decimals.
This is the console:

```
Enter your weight: 44
Enter your height: 182
0.000
```

Comment: But you're rounding the output. If you're getting a value smaller than your level of precision, what output do you expect?

Comment: I believe is the fact that the float behaves strange.

Comment: No, it's not because "the float behaves strange" it's because you're getting a number smaller than `0.000`. It's actually `0.000000133`. The output you get is to be expected.

Comment: 13.283 or 13.28. That the output I want.. the console without the round spits 1.328341987682647e-07

Comment: Then the issue is with your maths, not what the program outputs

Comment: Your formula for bmi is simply wrong. That's why you get so small values. BMI is kg/m².

Comment: bmi_metric = weight/((height^2)/(100^2)) @roganjosh You were right Forgot the fraction parenthesis

Comment: Think what `100**2` will yield

Comment: @cdarke  The BMI formula is in Meters but i read cm for convenience so i needed to have 100 squared  to have in cm2. I found the problem . Ho do I mark for close?

Answer (score 2):

Everything works fine (bmi_metric in your case is super small, so rounding gives 0 indeed), but you have a wrong equation for BMI calculation:

```
#weight in kg
weight = float(input('Enter your weight: '))
#height in cm
height = float(input('Enter your height: '))

bmi_metric = weight/((height/100)**2)
print("{:.2f}".format(bmi_metric))
```